# Mnist recognition using keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, mnist

How can I train the model to recognize five numbers in one picture.
The code is as follows:

```
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dropout, Dense, Input
from keras.models import Model, Sequential

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
             activation='relu',
             input_shape=(28, 140, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
```

Here should be a loop for recognizing each number in the picture, but I don't know how to realize it.

```
model.add(Dense(11, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
          optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
          metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train,
      batch_size=1000,
      epochs=8,
      verbose=1,
      validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid))
```

The picture of combined mnist number is as follows:

[image: combined numbers in one picture]

Comment: To summarise, there are basically two approaches to this problem.  Preprocess the image with something like opencv to pull out the digits you want to identify and then run a standard single digit CNN OR do the whole thing with a CNN of some type as described below: a brute force CNN (trained it on multiple digits),  an RNN  etc.   If the images are predictably formatted, then opencv is a good choice, for now and is the route I have chosen, for now!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest two possible approaches:

**Case 1- The images are nicely structured.**

In the example you provided, this is indeed the case, so if your data looks like in the link you provided, I will suggest this approach.

In the link you provided, every image basically consists of 5 28-by-28 pixeled images stacked together. In this case, I would suggest to cut the images (that is, cut each image into 5 pieces), and train your model as with a usual MNIST data (for example, using the code you provided). Then, when you want to apply your model to classify new data, just cut each new image into 5 pieces as well. Classify each one of these 5 pieces using your model, and then just write these 5 numbers right next to the other as an output.

so regarding this sentence:

> Here should be a loop for recognizing each number in the picture, but
>   I don't know how to realize it

you don't need a `for` loop. Just cut your figures.

**Case 2- The images are not nicely structured.**

In this case, each image is labeled with 5 numbers. So each row in `y_train` and `y_valid`) will be a 0,1-vector with 55 entries. 
The first 11 entries is the one-hot encoding of the first number, the second 11 entries is the one-hot encoding of the second number and so on. So each row in `y_train` will have 5 entries equal 1, and the rest equal 0.

In addition, instead of using softmax activation on the output layer and `categorical_crossentropy` loss, use sigmoid activation function and 'binary_crossentropy' loss (see further discussion about the reasons [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41589126/what-is-the-replace-for-softmax-layer-in-case-more-than-one-output-can-be-activa) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44164749/how-does-keras-handle-multilabel-classification))

To summarize, replace this:

```
model.add(Dense(11, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
          optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
          metrics=['accuracy'])
```

with this:

```
model.add(Dense(55, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
          optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta())
```

Answer (score 2):

The classic work in this area is ['Multi-digit Number Recognition from Street View Imagery using Deep Convolutional Neural Networks'](http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.6082)

Keras model (functional, not sequential):

```
inputs = Input(shape=(28, 140, 1), name="input")
x = inputs
x = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 140, 1))(x)
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
digit1 = Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='digit1')(x)
digit2 = Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='digit2')(x)
digit3 = Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='digit3')(x)
digit4 = Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='digit4')(x)
digit5 = Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='digit5')(x)
predictions = [digit1,digit2,digit3,digit4,digit5]
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), metrics=['accuracy'], oss='categorical_crossentropy')
```

PS
You may use 11 classes for 10 digits and empty space.

Comment: All the answers are helpful, this seemed the closest answer for the original question and why I have awarded bonus here.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have a very well behaved image, all you have to do is expand the number of classes in your model.

You can use 5 times 11 classes instead of using just 11 classes.

The first 11 classes identify the first number, the following 11 classes identify the second number and so on. A total of 55 classes, 11 classes for each position in the image.

So, in short:

- X_training will be the entire image, as you have shown in the link, shaped as `(28,140)`, or `(140,28)`, depending on which methods you're using to load the images.
- Y_training will be a 55-element vector, shape `(55,)`, telling which numbers are in each quadrant.

Example: for the first image, with 9,7,5,4,10, you'd create `Y_training` with the following positions containing the value 1:

- `Y_training[9] = 1`
- `Y_training[18] = 1 #(18=7+11)`
- `Y_training[27] = 1 #(27=5+22)`
- `Y_training[37] = 1 #(37=4+33)`
- `Y_training[54] = 1 #(54=10+44)`

Create your model layers the way you want, pretty much the same as a regular MNIST model, that means: no need to try loops or things like that.

But it will probably need to be a little bigger than before.

You will not be able to use `categorical_crossentropy` anymore, sice you will have 5 correct classes per image instead of just 1. If you're using "sigmoid" activations at the end, `binary_crossentropy` should be a good replacement.

Make sure your last layer fits the 55-element vector, such as `Dense(55)`, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been tackled by Yann LeCun in the 90's. You can find demos and papers on his [website](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/lenet/).

A not so general solution is to train a CNN on single digits MNIST and use this CNN to perform inference on images like the one you provided. Prediction is done by sliding the trained CNN on the multi-digit image and applying post processing to aggregate the results and possibly estimating the bounding boxes.

A very general solution that can handle a variable number of number and of different scales and positions is to build a model that is able to predict the bounding boxes of the numbers and perform classification on them. There's a recent history of such models with R-CNN, Fast-RCNN and [Faster-RCNN](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.01497).

You can find a python implementation of Faster-RCNN on [github.](https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn)