# Tensorflow structured data model.predict() returns incorrect probabilities

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm trying to follow a Tensorflow tutorial (i'm a beginner) for [structured data models](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/feature_columns) with some changes along the way.

My purpose is to create a model to which i provide data (in csv format) that looks something like this (the example has only 2 features but i want to extend it after i figure it out):

```
power_0,power_1,result
0.2,0.3,draw
0.8,0.1,win
0.3,0.1,draw
0.7,0.2,win
0.0,0.4,lose
```

I created the model using the following code:

```
def get_labels(df, label, mapping):
    raw_y_true = df.pop(label)
    y_true = np.zeros((len(raw_y_true)))
    for i, raw_label in enumerate(raw_y_true):
        y_true[i] = mapping[raw_label]
    return y_true


tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()

mapping_to_numbers = {'win': 0, 'draw': 1, 'lose': 2}

data_frame = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
data_frame.head()

train, test = train_test_split(data_frame, test_size=0.2)
train, val = train_test_split(train, test_size=0.2)

train_labels = np.array(get_labels(train, label='result', mapping=mapping_to_numbers))
val_labels = np.array(get_labels(val, label='result', mapping=mapping_to_numbers))
test_labels = np.array(get_labels(test, label='result', mapping=mapping_to_numbers))

train_features = np.array(train)
val_features = np.array(val)
test_features = np.array(test)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', input_shape=(train_features.shape[-1],)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='sigmoid'),
])

model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='binary_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy'],
    run_eagerly=True)

epochs = 10
batch_size = 100
history = model.fit(
    train_features,
    train_labels,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=(val_features, val_labels))

input_data_frame = pd.read_csv('input.csv')
input_data_frame.head()

input_data = np.array(input_data_frame)

print(model.predict(input_data))
```

input.csv looks as following:

```
power_0,power_1
0.8,0.1
0.7,0.2
```

And the actual result is:

```
[[0.00604381 0.00242573 0.00440606]
 [0.01321151 0.00634229 0.01041476]]
```

I expected to get the probability for each label ('win', 'draw' and 'lose'), can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works well for me with your example:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(train_features.shape[-1],)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax'),
])

model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy'],
    run_eagerly=True)
```

Using ***Flatten* Layer**

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!! your suggestion for using `Flatten` layer together with `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` loss function made the difference. My model's accuracy is now 0.97-1 (depending on the training data) and the `predict` function results actually make scene!

Answer (score 3):

Use softmax activation in this line `tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='sigmoid')`.

Comment: i tried this but now i'm getting `[[0.33328226 0.33350918 0.33320865]]` or similar for each input and also the accuracy dropped due to this change from 0.6 to 0.2-0.3

Comment: @AlonYampolski Does model converge?

Comment: Not sure what model convergence means, as I said I'm pretty new to tensorflow ☺️

Comment: Oh, it's ok. How many epochs do you train the model? Does the validation loss stop decreasing?

Comment: while using `sigmoid` the validation loss was moving between -4.08 and -0.22, when using 'softmax' it's steady on 1.1. i set epochs to 10

Answer (score 0):

I have to write my suggestions here because i cant comment yet.
@zihaozhihao is right you have to use softmax instead of sigmoid because you dont work with a binary problem. Another problem might be your loss function which is:

```
model.compile(
optimizer='adam',
loss='binary_crossentropy',
metrics=['accuracy'],
run_eagerly=True)
```

Try to use `loss='categorical_crossentropy',`because you are working with a multilabel classification. You could read more about multilable classification [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/05/07/multi-label-classification-with-keras/) and [here](https://www.depends-on-the-definition.com/guide-to-multi-label-classification-with-neural-networks/).

As for your propability question. You get the propability of each class for your two test inputs.For example: 
  `win         draw       loss
[[0.00604381 0.00242573 0.00440606]
 [0.01321151 0.00634229 0.01041476]]` 
The Problem is your loss function and the activation function which leads to strange propability values. You might want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44164749/how-does-keras-handle-multilabel-classification) post here for more information.

Hope this helps a little and feel free to ask.

Comment: i tried the changes you suggested but unfortunately i'm still getting unexpected results: `[[0.33328226 0.33350918 0.33320865]]`

Comment: But you now get a distribution if I'm correct. It sayes 33% win 33% draw 33% loss if I'm not mistaken? Maybe you can tell me what you expected so I can try to understand :)

Comment: The problem is that the distribution is almost even for every input I tried, I expected that i.e. for a win I will get `[[0.7, 0.2, 0.1]]` with uneven distribution of probability

Comment: May I ask how many trainings exampels do you use and what is your training accuracy/loss vs validation accuracy/loss? Because it might be that your implementation is fine, your model is just underfitting :) Moreover you might want to take a higher number for epochs to give your model time to acually learn from your data. You train only for 10 epochs which is quiet a low number for learning something.

Comment: after changing the loss to `categorical_crossentropy` the training results are `loss: 3.1619 - acc: 0.2797 - val_loss: 3.3370 - val_acc: 0.1500` and validation are `loss: 3.3287 - acc: 0.1400`. I have 1000 samples but i can generate as much as i want

Comment: Your loss is quite high and your accuracy quite low in train and val. Have you tried to increase the counts of epochs? Maybe to 100 to give your model more time to learn? As it is now your model really hasn't learned anything and is underfitting.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a multiclass classification problem, please use **categorical_crossentropy** instead of **binary_crossentropy** for **loss functio**n, also use **softmax** instead of **sigmoid** as **activation function**.

Also, you should increase your **epochs** for getting better convergence.